# How to reference an open workbook with a macro that is stored in my "Personal.xlsb" workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, new-operator

I am trying to copy data from any previously made workbook.  My macro works as far as selecting the file to copy from and up until the paste line.
It fails at
`ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Imported Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`
The "Imported Data" is sheet 4 in the currently open workbook.
I believe the problem might be that the macro is running from my "Personal.xlsb" workbook (which is blank) so it cant find the correct sheet to paste to.  How would I reference the current open workbook if the name changes each time a new one is made.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file 
    & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1:F27").Copy
        ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Imported 
    Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
    
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing the code. You probably need to capture `ActiveWorkbook` at the beginning: `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume it, but do it prior to your call to `Application.Workbooks.Open()` because that changes the current workbook.

Before you set OpenBook, set a new variable `Set TargetRange = Worksheets("Imported  Data").Range("A1")`. (or you could use `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`...) Then you can change

```
ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Imported Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

to

```
TargetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```